# Contour plot includes negative values when my dataset is positive using plotly in R

Tags: r, plot, plotly, distribution, contour

I'm trying to make a contour plot of a bivariate distribution of a set of sampled parameters. I've used plotly in R, however, the plot includes negative values, but my dataset is positive.

The code what I am using is as follows,

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = lambda1, y = v1, type = "histogram2dcontour", showlegend=FALSE)
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Treatment 1 Weibull Bivariate Density Plot", 
                      xaxis = list(title = "Lambda"), 
                      yaxis = list(title = "nu"))
```

As a result I get this,

[image: Contour plot]

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Forgive me, but what is negative on that plot?

Comment: Oh, do you mean the stuff left of "Lambda = 0"? If so, that's because contour plots tend to apply "smoothing", which does not typically do an immediate "drop off". (Smoothing by itself doesn't know the context of the numbers.)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've added line=list(smoothing=0) to remove smoothing, however, the plot still crosses 0, do you happen to know if there is any way to stop this?

Comment: Try `xbins = list(start=-0.5), ybins = list(start=-0.5)`. I don't know why `-0.5` and not `0`.

Comment: This has worked, thank you!